# Unexpected token with react

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

Getting unexpected while running. I am trying to load the InfiniteLoader of react virtualized. Would like to know how to call the API through this component If any example is available. I have taken the component from https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md
I am using the example from https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/InfiniteLoader

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { InfiniteLoader, List } from 'react-virtualized';
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'; // only needs to be imported once

export default class MyList extends React.PureComponent {

  const remoteRowCount

  const list = [];

  function isRowLoaded ({ index }) {
    return !!list[index];
  }

  function loadMoreRows ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
  }

  function rowRenderer ({ key, index, style}) {
    return (
      <div
        key={key}
        style={style}
      >
        {list[index]}
      </div>
    )
  }

  //Render the list from this function
  render() {
    return(
      <InfiniteLoader
    isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
    loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
    rowCount={remoteRowCount}
  >
    {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
      <List
        height={200}
        onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
        ref={registerChild}
        rowCount={remoteRowCount}
        rowHeight={20}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        width={300}
      />
    )}
  </InfiniteLoader>
    );
  }

}
```

Getting the below given exception

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/code/react-starter/src/Components/MyList/MyList.js: Unexpected token (8:8)

   6 | export default class MyList extends React.PureComponent {
   7 |
>  8 |   const remoteRowCount
     |         ^
   9 |
  10 |   const list = [];
  11 |
```

Comment: It's because you declared `remoteRowCount` and `list` inside your component. Put them above the class definition (or if you want them to be part of the component, add them properly in the constructor)

Comment: I would like to know these kind of rules , where would I find them ?

Comment: Just have a look at the React documentation, it shows you how to set up a component. For the sake of adding properties to your component in the constructor (as either object properties of the actual component, or as state values) check out the lifecycle and constructor stuff: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks , but for this moment , what would be solution to see this component working

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, move them out of your class definition

Comment: I tried that still it gives exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the follow code.

Basically, I：

1. moved `list` and `remoteRowCount` to MyList's state.
2. change `isRowLoaded` `loadMoreRows` `rowRenderer` to MyList's instance method. You may also want to do the same thing to `onRowsRendered` and etc.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import { InfiniteLoader, List } from 'react-virtualized';
   import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'; // only needs to be imported once

   export default class MyList extends React.PureComponent {
     constructor() {
       super();

       this.state = {
         remoteRowCount: 0,
         list: [],
       };

       this.isRowLoaded = this.isRowLoaded.bind(this);
       this.loadMoreRows = this.loadMoreRows.bind(this);
       this.rowRenderer = this.rowRenderer.bind(this);
     }

     isRowLoaded ({ index }) {
       return !!this.state.list[index];
     }

     loadMoreRows ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
     }

     rowRenderer ({ key, index, style}) {
       return (
         <div
           key={key}
           style={style}
         >
           {this.state.list[index]}
         </div>
       )
     }

     //Render the list from this function
     render() {
       return(
         <InfiniteLoader
       isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded}
       loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows}
       rowCount={this.state.remoteRowCount}
     >
       {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
         <List
           height={200}
           onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
           ref={registerChild}
           rowCount={remoteRowCount}
           rowHeight={20}
           rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
           width={300}
         />
       )}
     </InfiniteLoader>
       );
     }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Where to find the nice tutorials about react

Comment: Thank you very much , I would like to know from where the data is coming in this example into the grid , I cant see any api

Comment: the related code is [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/demo/Application.js#L45)